# creating hybrid application using angular js and angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular5

I am planning to create new features in angular 5 and then integrate them in my already created angular js application using the concept of hybrid application in angular. I am willing to save my effort in migrating the js application to angular 5. So, wanted to know the pros and cons of this approach in term of eficiency and is it okay to host an application in hybrid state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://impekable.com/native-vs-hybrid-mobile-app-development/

Comment: I don't think it's possible in any decent way to create a combined app of angularjs and angular5... either migrate the whole app to angular5/6 or keep using angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible have hybrid application and to migrate AngularJS to Angular 4+, step by step.

There are so many links available which can help you with this.

Here are the some of the links to get you started:

1. To understand basic hybrid app -> https://github.com/basavarajnb/NgUpgrade-Angular-CLI
2. Official Angular Migration -> https://angular.io/guide/upgrade
3. Tutorial 1 -> https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b

Tutorial 2 -> https://yakovfain.com/2017/08/01/migrating-your-apps-from-angularjs-to-angular/

4. 9 Lessons Learned on an AngularJS to Angular 4 Upgrade  https://www.intertech.com/Blog/9-lessons-learned-on-an-angularjs-to-angular-4-upgrade/

**All the best**